# subtract the share of the current month from the share of the previous month within the same year

Tags: r, dplyr

For each year, I want to subtract the share of the current month from the share of the previous month within the same year, except for January where the share of January is subtracted from the share of December of the previous year.

This is what I attempted but instead of getting my desired output, I'm getting NAs:

```
data %>%
  arrange(month) %>%
  mutate(unique = ave(month, month, FUN = seq_along)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(
    lags = ifelse(
      month == 1, 
      share - share[month == 12 & year == unique(year) - 1], 
      share - share[month == month - 1 & year == unique(year)]
    )
  )
```

However, it works fine when I run these codes

```
mutate(lag = ifelse(month == 1, share[month == 2] - share[month == 1], 
                      ifelse(month == 2, share[month == 3] - share[month == 2],
                             ifelse(month == 3, share[month == 4] - share[month == 3],
                                    ifelse(month == 4, share[month == 5] - share[month == 4],
                                           ifelse(month == 5, share[month == 6] - share[month == 5],
                                                  ifelse(month == 6, share[month == 7] - share[month == 6],
                                                         ifelse(month == 7, share[month == 8] - share[month == 7],
                                                                ifelse(month == 8, share[month == 9] - share[month == 8],
                                                                       ifelse(month == 9, share[month == 10] - share[month == 9],
                                                                              ifelse(month == 10, share[month == 11] - share[month == 10],
                                                                                     ifelse(month == 11, share[month == 12] - share[month == 11], NA)
```

But the issue is how can I specify when month=12 and year=2000, subtract share from month=1 and year=2001. When month=12 and year=2014, subtract share from month=1 and year=2015.

```
data <- data.frame(
  month = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12),
  year = c(2000, 2000, 2015, 2000, 2000, 2015, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2014),
  share = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.3)
)
```

Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 26 × 5
# Groups:   year [4]
   month  year share unique  lag1
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  2000   0.2      1    0.4
 2     1  2000   0.4      2    0.3
 3     1  2015   0.1      3    0.2
 4     2  2000   0.6      1    -0.4
 5     2  2000   0.7      2    0.1
 6     2  2015   0.3      3    NA
 7     3  2000   0.2      1    0.3
 8     3  2000   0.8      2    -0.7
 9     4  2000   0.5      1    -0.3
10     4  2000   0.1      2    NA
11     5  2000   0.2      1    NA
12     6  2001   0.4      1    NA
13     6  2001   0.1      2    NA
14     7  2014   0.6      1    -0.3
15     7  2014   0.7      2    NA
16     8  2014   0.3      1    -0.1
17     9  2014   0.2      1    NA
18     9  2014   0.8      2    NA
19    10  2000   0.5      1    -0.3
20    10  2000   0.1      2    NA
21    11  2000   0.2      1    NA
22    11  2001   0.4      2    0.2
23    11  2001   0.1      3    0.6
24    12  2001   0.6      1    NA
25    12  2001   0.7      2    NA
26    12  2014   0.3      3    -0.2
```

Comment: How can you do this if you do not have unique values for `share` for each month/year combination? January 2000 has a share of 0.2 and a share of 0.4 - which of these should be used to calculate the value for February 2000?

Comment: the first share of January 2000 will be subtracted from the first share of February 2000. If January 2000 has more rows of share, put NA.

Comment: Hey, @Victoria, when you say "share of the previous month within the same year", you mean the real one, even if it's missing from data (eg. march-april), or previous one that it's in the table (eg. july-november, 2001)?

Comment: Hello, @AdrianoMello. So from the table, `share` of March 2000 are 0.2 and 0.8, April 2000 are 0.5 and 0.1. Taking the difference would give 0.3 and -0.7 which are `lag1` in rows 7 and 8. For February 2000 `share` values are 0.6 and 0.7, subtracting values from March 2000 would give -0.4 and 0.1, which are values of `lag1` in rows 4 and 5. Notice that because there is no March 2015, therefore row 6 in `lag1` is NA. I'm not sure if this clarifies your doubt, please let me know there is still any confusion.

Comment: For January, I want to subtract the `share` from December in the previous year. From the table `share` of January 2015 is `0.1` and December 2014 is `0.3`. So the `lag1` should be `-0.2` which is the value in row 26 of `lag1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  arrange(month) %>% 
  mutate(diff = share[pmatch(month + 1, month)] - share,
         year2 = if_else(month == 1, year - 1, year), .by = year) %>%
  mutate(diff = coalesce(diff, share[pmatch(month - 11, month)] - share),
         .by = year2) %>%
  select(-year2)
```

Here `pmatch` is used instead of `match` because values once matched in `pmatch` are excluded from the search for subsequent matches. A simple example is that `match(c(1,1), c(1,1))` returns 1, 1, whereas `pmatch(c(1,1), c(1,1))` returns 1, 2. I use this feature to deal with the repeated measures in some pairs of year-month.

###### Output

```
   month year share diff
1      1 2000   0.2  0.4
2      1 2000   0.4  0.3
3      1 2015   0.1  0.2
4      2 2000   0.6 -0.4
5      2 2000   0.7  0.1
6      2 2015   0.3   NA
7      3 2000   0.2  0.3
8      3 2000   0.8 -0.7
9      4 2000   0.5 -0.3
10     4 2000   0.1   NA
11     5 2000   0.2   NA
12     6 2001   0.4   NA
13     6 2001   0.1   NA
14     7 2014   0.6 -0.3
15     7 2014   0.7   NA
16     8 2014   0.3 -0.1
17     9 2014   0.2   NA
18     9 2014   0.8   NA
19    10 2000   0.5 -0.3
20    10 2000   0.1   NA
21    11 2000   0.2   NA
22    11 2001   0.4  0.2
23    11 2001   0.1  0.6
24    12 2001   0.6   NA
25    12 2001   0.7   NA
26    12 2014   0.3 -0.2
```

Comment: Ah yes, yours looks correct. I had included the `unique` value from the post above, which gave a different result. I believe this answer looks correct.